# MySQL No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I have been developing a testimonial app for a clients facebook page that she can edit herself!
I am having a problem with inserting it into the database! I has wrote it in MySQLi forst but have now gone back to basics and i am using this code here...

```
<?php
      $testtitle = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_tt']);
      $testbody = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_tb']);
      $compowner = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_co']);
      $ownertitle = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_ot']);
      $compname = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_cn']);
      $compwebsite = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ts_cw']);

      include_once "../php_includes/db_conx.php";

      $sql = "INSERT INTO testimonials (testtitle, testbody, compowner, ownertitle, compname, compwebsite)
              VALUES ('$testtitle', '$testbody', '$compowner', '$ownertitle', '$compname', '$compwebsite')";
      if (!mysql_query($sql, $connection)){
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  exit();
?>
```

And here is the simple form i am using! and yea i know it's in a table! i just wanted to make something quick and easy...

```
<form method="post" action="testimonial_new_parse.php" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
  <tr>
    <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#F5E4A9">Testimonial Full Title</td>
    <td width="88%" bgcolor="#F5E4A9"><input name="ts_tt" type="text" size="80" maxlength="64" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#DAEAFA">Testimonial Body</td>
    <td bgcolor="#DAEAFA"><textarea name="ts_tb" cols="60" rows="16"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">Company Owner</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="ts_co" type="text" maxlength="64" size="80" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">Owner Title</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="ts_ot" type="text" maxlength="64" size="80"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">Company Name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="ts_cn" type="text" maxlength="64" size="80" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#D7EECC">Company Website</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D7EECC"><input name="ts_cw" type="text" maxlength="64" size="80" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="ts_button" value="Create this Testimonial now" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

The problem is I keep getting is that Np Database has been selected!
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have in `../php_includes/db_conx.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the connect and select of the database. These 2 steps should come before you run the query.

From the php documentation(adjust accordingly):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will have to do with your $connection variable, how do you initialize it?

As mentioned by others already, you need to initialize it properly and select a database, like this :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Also note that the MySQLi extension is preferred over MySQL, so use that if you can.

Also, note that your HTML code will not work either, your 'tr' and 'td' must be in a table, like this :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the connection file is not correct. Check the connection file and then try again.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your answer is a good effort, take a moment to study the question first. You see, this question is over a year old, and already answered, so it's unlikely to be revised again by the OP. Also, for the future, consider giving a more complete answer and, if possible, accompanied by code examples. 

Also I somewhat fail to notice any relation between your answer and the question.